# How to make a function to recover period of times in React-native?

Tags: react-native, date, momentjs

Iwould like to select multiple periode of times in react-native and I'm pretty lost to do it.
I understand I need to use "Moment" but I'm a little stuck...
For example I guess that "last week" is "`moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();`"

But how to check the last week for example from monday to last sunday ?

Thanks a lot for any help
The function I"d like to set up is :

```
export default class MyTrips extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.state = {
      currentDate: new Date(),
      markedDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  };
  }

      execAction = (val) => {
        switch (val) {
          case "this week":
          moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();
            break;
          case "Last week": (from monday to last sunday)
            break;
          case "this month":
             moment().subtract(1, 'month').calendar();
            break;
          case "Last month": (last entire month)
            break;
          case "This year":
               moment().subtract(1, 'year').calendar();
            break;
          case "Last year":
            break;
          case "30 last days":
             moment().subtract(30, 'days').calendar();
            break;
          case "90 last days":
             moment().subtract(90, 'days').calendar();
              break;
          case "12 last months":
             moment().subtract(12, 'months').calendar();
            break;
      default:
          //Alert.alert("[" + val + "] No action defined...");
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `moment().startOf('week')` to get to the beginning of this week, from there you can move to last week like this:

```js
moment().startOf('week').subtract(6, 'days').calendar()
```

Comment: Oh great thank you so much . 
And how to extract an entire week like last week for example ? I mean if we take today thursday the 30th of july how to select automatically the last entire week that is past  ? from monday 20th of july to sunday 26th of july for example ? is it possible to get the entire period of 7 days

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I resolved using : 
case "Last week":
          console.log(moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek'),
                  moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek'));
          break;